# React + ASP.Net-Core CORS Problems

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, http-status-code-400, connection-refused

While CORS is a big issue when working ReactJS in combination with ASP.Net-Core I figured out how to enable CORS so when accessing my UI (`http://localhost:3000`) which uses SignalR/REST-Calls against the API (`http://localhost:51761`).

Here the `Startup.cs`

```cs
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddCors(option =>
                {
                    option.AddPolicy("myCors",
                        builder =>
                        {
                            builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin =>
                            {
                                if (origin.StartsWith("http://localhost")) return true;
                                if (origin.StartsWith("http://vdedarh02331")) return true;
                                if (origin.StartsWith("http://10.65.1.23")) return true;
                                return false;
                            });
                        });
                });
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "SimpleAPI", Version = "v1"}); });
            }
    
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    app.UseSwagger();
                    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SimpleAPI v1"));
                }
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseCors("myCors");
                
    
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
            }
```

On my React Application I am doing the following API call:

```js
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:51761/Simple/Login")
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log("Trying to use IP");
        axios
          .post("10.65.1.23:51761/Simple/Login")
          .then((resp) => console.log(resp))
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      });
```

Opening the UI via Browser with URL `http://10.65.1.23:3000` works fine. Doing a request against the API results into following error.

[image: Calling the API though UI on different machine than localhost]

It makes sense that calling `localhost:51761` wouldnt work because the browser is trying to call the API on the browsers machine.

When debugging the server code on the inner function of `SetIsOriginAllowed` I recognized that the origin will always be evaluated everytime I do a request when using the UI on my dev-machine (`localhost`) but never when using a different machine.

Did I missunderstood CORS or did a wrong setup?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem by myself.

So actually what you need to do is to set the proxy in your react projects `package.json` to the URL of the API. In addition you need to make your http-request be dynamically and set the content-type of the request to non-`text/html`

So changing the client-code from

```js
axios
      .post("http://localhost:51761/Simple/Login")
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log("Trying to use IP");
        axios
          .post("10.65.1.23:51761/Simple/Login")
          .then((resp) => console.log(resp))
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      });
```

to

```js
    axios
      .post(
        "/Simple/Login",
        {},
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log("Trying to use IP");
        axios
          .post(
            "/Simple/Login",
            {},
            { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
          )
          .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

while configuring, you need to mention the port number with URL.

In **Startup.cs**

```
builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:51761")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
```

Also, specify at the controller level

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
public class SimpleController : Controller
```

Comment: This didn't help. I also dont know why I should additionally enable CORS in controller-level. Also my configuration contians a function which checks the origin.